# Receiving Non object error when doing a Foreach in a blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving an error when doing the following foreach in a blade :

```
@foreach($updt_12 as $updt_12_qa)
<input type = "hidden" name = "id"  id="id" value="{{$updt_12_qa->qatype}}">

@endforeach
```

Error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

qatype is fixed for all fields in the loop, so how can I use the value in this array instead of sending a variable again from the controller just for qatype?

dd($update_12);

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#371 ▼
    +"id": 21
    +"created_at": "2019-10-17 13:21:22"
    +"updated_at": "2019-10-17 13:21:22"
    +"title": "q2"
    +"body": """
       \r\n
         ans 2
      """
    +"ttype": 0
    +"cat": 0
    +"a_id": 21
    +"tag": ""
    +"appr": 0
    +"user_id": 1
    +"comment_id": 0
    +"parent_id": null
    +"ppoints": null
    +"status": 0
    +"arank": 1
    +"qatype": 1
    +"country": "Egypt"
    +"wwide": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: show dd($updt_12) output of this in controller

Comment: Agreeing with @Rahul. It's possible that $updt_12 represents a QueryBuilder instance and not a Collection. You may need to add ```->get();``` to the end of your query for $updt_12 .

Comment: update this in question. What are gonna get from this? we want to seee

Comment: Updated question

Comment: And `dd($updt_12_qa)`?

Comment: `$update_12` is not the same as `$updt_12`. Try `dd($updt_12);`

Comment: I returned $update_12 because this is the array coming from the query : return view('winPolitic')
  ->with('updt_12', $update_12)

Comment: Try `<?php var_dump($updt_12_qa); ?>` inside of your loop, before your input line. You may have some that are objects, but there may be a bad result in there.

Comment: You could also try: `<?php print gettype( updt_12_qa ); ?>` in your loop. and if any of them are not "object", then investigate why, or explicitly exclude those items from your view:  `@if( gettype( updt_12_qa ) !== "object" ) <input ...> @endif`

Comment: I'm not sure if this was a bug. I noticed that after deleting all the content of the view, still it showed the same content, and ofcourse I was working in the correct blade. After many trials I changed the uppercase "P" in winPolitic in the : return view('winPolitic') ->with('updt_12', $update_12) to lowercase, and things started to work. I'm quite sure there are no other versions with lowercase p. I'm quite confused now, and will certainly never use upercases in Laravel blades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have array into array then use like this.

```
@foreach($updt_12[0] as $updt_12_qa)
     <input type = "hidden" name = "id"  id="id" value="{{$updt_12_qa->qatype}}">
@endforeach
```